# Hit Test bounce

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, 2d-games

I'm trying to make sort of a Balloon fight game for flash. I have a ceiling at the top of the screen, so when the player hits it, it should bounce off of it. Problem is, I don't know how to go about doing that. Here is the code.

I was messing around with numbers. In the upBumping variable, where the problem lies, I wanted to have the character bounce down once it hits, but it only does this once. After, it just goes through the ceiling. Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way?

```
//gravity and stuff
var gravity:Number = 0.3;
var fall:Number = 0.3;
var downBumping:Boolean = false;
var upBumping:Boolean = false;

//direction I guess
var leftKeyDown:Boolean = false;
var upKeyDown:Boolean = false;
var rightKeyDown:Boolean = false;
var spaceKeyDown:Boolean = false;

//character movement ya'll
var mainSpeed:Number = 6;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, game);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);

function game(e:Event): void{

//if certain keys are down then move dat fool
    if(leftKeyDown){
        Monkey.x -= mainSpeed;
    }
    if(rightKeyDown){
        Monkey.x += mainSpeed;
    }
    if(upKeyDown){

        fall = fall-0.9;
        gravity = 0.3;
    }
    if(Floor.hitTestObject(Monkey)){
        downBumping = true;
        trace("downBumping");
    }
    if(Ceiling.hitTestObject(Monkey)){
        upBumping = true;
        trace("upBumping");
        trace(Monkey.y);
    }
    if(upBumping){
        Monkey.y += 20;
    }
    Monkey.y = Monkey.y+fall;
    gravity = gravity*1.0;
    fall = fall+gravity;

}
```

Comment: This is a very broad question, and those kind of questions are not usually very welcomed in SO. If you really want to make your own physics engine you are going to need to dig deeper than hitTestObject. You could also use any of the physics engines available for AS3 such as http://box2dflash.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Pier: I respectfully disagree. There is a simple code snippet which illustrates what Bindlestick wants to do, and for a simple game a physics engine is often unnecessary.

Comment: I suppose it's a subjective matter. That is why I didn't (and won't) downvote the question. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do jumping and bouncing - this does not include other code like moving left to right since you already got that

```
function game(e:Event):void {
    if(jumping){
        yVelocity += 0.1; //gravity
        Monkey.y += yVelocity;
        if(Floor.hitTestObject(Monkey)){
            jumping = false;
            while(Floor.hitTestObject(Monkey)){
                y--;
            }
        }
        if(Ceiling.hitTestObject(Monkey)){
            yVelocity = 0;
            while(Ceiling.hitTestObject(Monkey)){
                y++;
            }
        }
    }
    if(upKeyDown && !jumping){
        jumping = true;
        yVelocity = -3;
    }
}
```

Obviously, declare the variables used in this example.

Comment: Thanks, gladoscc. Am I replacing jumping and yVelocity with my gravity and fall variables?